# Capybara starts puma twice after upgrading

Tags: cucumber, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara

After I upgraded capybara from `2.13.0` to `3.5.0` I see the following output when I am running the cucumber features. Seems like that capybara starts Puma server twice

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 7380
Capybara starting Puma...
* Version 3.12.0 , codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:58798
Using the default profile...
Capybara starting Puma...
* Version 3.12.0 , codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:58883
```

I am using ruby on rails version `5.1.2`

How to prevent Capybara from starting Puma twice and suppress this `Capybara starting Puma...` output?

Comment: Puma output can be silenced by passing options when setting Capybara.server. Exactly how depends on your setup. Please post your Capybara and RSpec setup. Two servers would be started if you changed Capybara.app or server settings after Capybara already started one. Your spec_helper. rails_helper. And cucumber env should show if that’s the case, so please add those to your question

Comment: Did you guys find a solution? It seems weird that puma starts twice. Silenting outputs doesn't feel like solving the issue properly :)

Comment: Hi @knagode, not yet. Working on the other stuff now, plan to look at it later

Comment: Did you guys find a solution?